# Agoda api integration

Tags: xml, api

I am building a channel manager and I stared with agoda. I need to push rates and inventory. I know I need to push data as `XML`.

How to send the `XML` string to the EndPoint?
for example if the endpoint is

`https://sandbox-distribution-xml.agoda.com/api/ari?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

1) what is the `apikey`, where can I get it?

2) how to send the `XML` to EndPoint? (parameters)

sample `XML` is,

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request timestamp="23232931804" type="1">
    <criteria property_id="1949542">
        <inventory>
            <update room_id="5478687">
            <date_range from="2015-10-01" to="2015-10-10">
                <dow>1</dow>
                <dow>2</dow>
                <dow>3</dow>
                <dow>4</dow>
                <dow>5</dow>
                <dow>6</dow>
                <dow>7</dow>
            </date_range>           
            <allotment>9</allotment>
            <restrictions>
                <closed>false</closed>
                <ctd>false</ctd>
                <cta>true</cta>
                </restrictions>
            </update>
        </inventory>
    </criteria>
</request>
```

Comment: Hi Kelum. I know this has been 2 years, but I am trying to connect to Agoda as well.  Would it be possible for me to have your email?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to (1) is that you must register on the https://partners.agoda.com and then you will be able to automatically verify your website (in several ways, I remember at least 2: adding a META tag in your HTML code or uploading an HTML file that they give you on your domain).

The answer to (2) is slightly more complicated and it probably changed in the past years, but it will actually depend on the programming language that you are using. If it's PHP, then you probably want to check the curl command.